# Detect when a css rule has been applied from a JS added stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css

> Question has been asked before likely but no satisfactory answer as of
> 2020.

Given this **example**:

```
 `.bar { height: ${randomHeight()}px }`
```

which is then inserted as a **style** **tag** to the HEAD element.

becoming:

```
<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="116">
    .bar { height: 112px }
</style>
```

as an example.

Now, this won't have immediate effect, so immediately after inserting it to the document, I won't be able to **log** the height of the bar for instance.

However, if I setTimeout(..., 1000) I can read the height from the element eventually.

Is there **a way** to **listen** or **detect** when **ANY** style tag has been inserted has been **applied**, without resorting to arbitrary setTimeout?

Not interested in this height case alone, but a general solution where any stylesheet added has been applied.

Comment: This question feels like [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), since your question seem to be focused on a legit solution rather than a hack. Could you describe your use case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for changes being made to the DOM tree. Make sure the snippet below runs before a style tag is inserted to the HEAD so it can catch the changes.

```
// Select the node that will be observed for mutations
const targetNode = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
// Set childList to true as we want to observe if style tag has been added as a child of the head element.)
const config = { attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: false };

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
        if (mutation.addedNodes.length && mutation.addedNodes[0].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'style') {
            console.log('A style tag has been added to the HEAD:', mutation.addedNodes[0]); 
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

Comment: I really like this solution. I would just point out that this may not capture "every" instance, only those on or within the head element  - but definitely an elegant approach.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of an alternative answer, one which requires no polling, you could use the animation end event, it's an event triggered when a css animation ends.

You can learn more about this event here, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event